how to use expo-sqlite react-native application problem
I’m developing an application and I would like to use a db to store data so I don’t constantly ask it to the server, but I’m having problems with expo-sqlite, can anyone explain me what I’m doing wrong ?
i have a file database.js
`import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';
const db = SQLite.openDatabase('myDatabase.db');
export const createTables = () => {db.transaction(tx => {tx.executeSql(CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (             uid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,             picture TEXT,             pversion INTEGER           ));});}; then I have a viewmodel for data management where I would use the storemanager`import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';import { fetchTopUsers, userDetails } from '../api';import { useSession } from './../utils/SessionManager';import StorageManager  from './../utils/StorageManager';
export const useUserListViewModel = () => {// const [userList, setUserList] = useState([]);const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);const { sid } = useSession();const [userTopList, setUserTopList] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {const initializeAndFetchData = async () => {try {if (sid) {const users = await fetchTopUsers(sid);StorageManager.initialize();await updateUsers(users);} else {console.log("UserVMlist sid mancante o non valido");}} catch (error) {console.error('Errore durante l'inizializzazione o il recupero dei dati:', error);} finally {setIsLoading(false);}};
initializeAndFetchData();
}, [sid]);`
this is my storagemanager
`import { createTables, insertItem, getItems, deleteItem } from './../database';
class StorageManager {
static initialize() {
createTables();
}
static addItem(value) {
return insertItem(value);
}
static fetchItems() {
return getItems();
}
static removeItem(id) {
return deleteItem(id);
}
}
export default StorageManager;`
these are my dependencies
 "dependencies": {         "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.2",         "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.23.1",         "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",         "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.19",         "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.12",         "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.23",         "axios": "^1.6.8",         "expo": "^51.0.5",         "expo-location": "~16.5.5",         "expo-sqlite": "~14.0.3",         "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",         "expo-vector-icons": "^10.0.1",         "react": "18.2.0",         "react-native": "^0.74.1",         "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.14.0",         "react-native-maps": "^1.11.3",         "react-native-reanimated": "^3.7.1",         "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.9.0",         "react-native-screens": "^3.29.0"       },
I expect it to work, but I have these two errors and I don’t understand how to fix it
ERROR  TypeError: SQLite.openDatabase is not a function (it is undefined), js engine: hermes
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called., js engine: hermes


use this version:     "expo": "~50.0.14",

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
